# Continuation of existing curved edges to close mesh body

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, edges, fcurves

I’m totally new to blender; this may be a really obvious question! I just wondered if anybody can help.

I created this mesh body[image]

I then smoothed the vertical edge vertices.This had the desired effect of smoothing the curves, but shortened the overall length of the vertex edges. This has left the top and bottom of my mesh open.

I would like to close both ends of the mesh using a continuation of the smooth curved edge vertices.

As shown below: the open end(circled red) is where I’d like to continue the edge vertices(yellow) to a closed point or small flat face. I need the continuation to follow the smooth curve/angle of the existing edge vertices

[image]

Any help or suggestions of a way to do this would be much appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org) Please don't post photos of your monitor, these are hard to read because we can't tell if we are looking at a reflection, a screen artifact or an actual issue with the model.

Comment: Apologies,  I will bear this in mind in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the top edge which you want to extend, hit <kbd>G</kbd> twice to activate *Edge Slide* mode. Now hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and you can move the vertices outwards along the projected edges. As soon as your vertices are close enough together press <kbd>LMB</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> to apply the transformation. Now close the top by hitting <kbd>F</kbd> to fill it or  <kbd>M</kbd> to merge the vertices. But this extends the edges linear, it doesn't preserve the curvature.

Comment: This worked well thank you. Like you said, the edges are extended linear but this was close enough for the desired effect.